# Dojo currency text box - How to get value with ssjs

Tags: xpages

I'm using a Dojo currency text box and want to check with ssjs, if the box is empty or not.

Currently I'm using this:

```
if (wfDoc.getItemValueString("InvestmentAmount") == "")
```

But this code always tells me, that the box is empty, even if I have entered a value. So how can I check if the field is empty with ssjs?

Comment: Try wfDoc.getValue("InvestmentAmount")

Comment: have you tried == null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo Currency Text Box stores the value as a number, as does the Dojo Number Text Box. The Dojo Extension Library controls are based on the corresponding client-side Dojo dijits. Because they're all just HTML widgets extending the Dojo Validation Text Box, they have the "Text" in the control name. Remember Dojo is a web-based client-side Javascript framework, so it can only deal with text values. But because they're integrated into XPages which has server-side functionality, the Dojo Currency Text Box and Dojo Number Text Box convert the value to the correct back-end datatype, so a number.

Doing getItemValueString() on a number field returns an empty string. So Per is correct for using getValue().

Answer (score 0):

I ran a short test this should work.

```
<xe:djCurrencyTextBox
    id="djCurrencyTextBox1"
    value="#{document1.test}">
</xe:djCurrencyTextBox>

<xp:button
    value="test"
    id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:view.postScript("window.alert('Test"+java.lang.String.valueOf(document1.getValue('test')==null)+"');");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```